# why my page wont get my facebook name?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
<?php

require_once('facebook.php');

// require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'my_appid',
    'secret' => 'my_secret'
));


if($facebook->getUser() == 0){
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email'
    ));
    echo "<a href = '$login_url'>Login With Facebook</a>";
}
else{

    $api = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    echo "Hi " . $api[name];

    echo "<br><a href ='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

};

?>
```

i think i have my facebook sdk 3.2.3 working but somehow it keep return to logging page , when i click log in with facebook , facebook do ask me do i wanted to pass those data on , but when it redirect the url i cant echo my name , what is wrong ? do the getUser keep return = 0 ?

can anyone help me take a look ? i wanted to use 4.0 sdk but my friend sever is 5.2 below so i need to get this facebook loging working. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this a function? Maybe it's because you're constantly starting a new Facebook session?

Comment: is not a function , i only wanted to connect to facebook and get my name and email.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
 echo "Hi " . $api['name'];
```

This will work.

Comment: cant i keep return to the logging "echo "<a href = '$login_url'>Login With Facebook</a>";

Comment: i guess is the getUser return == 0

Comment: You can do this using php function. put your facebook api code in one php function and call it on some event.

Comment: Another thing you can do.... put your facebook api code in one php page and link that url in your <a href="$login_url"> Login with facebook </a>.

Comment: i wanted it logging with the same page , do i need redirect url ?

Comment: @cheok dee ........ so for that you can use redirect url as same page and use one $_GET variable. if that $_GET variable is found than it automatically active your fb api code.